# Rent a residential address

Tags: rental-property

I want to have a residential address in England or another country; I want to know is it possible to have it ?
If yes, is it possible to have document which states this address is on my hold such as utility bill or something else ?
emphasis : I just want to have a residential address and I do not want to live there.

Comment: By definition, a residential address is "where you live", so you can't not live at your residential address. Therefore, you need to clarify the question. E.g. "Can I have a mailing address at a place where I don't live?"

Comment: The OP may be actually looking to spoof a residental address.

Answer (score 2):

### Your residential address is the place where you live

A place that you own or rent but don’t live at, is not a residential address.

To be a resident of England or most other countries require that you live there for at least part of the year and have the appropriate citizenship or visa. For example, as an Australian I can (probably) get a work visa for the UK for up to 5 years - that will make me a resident for certain purposes like taxation but not for other purposes like immigration. Notwithstanding I will need to spend a significant portion of each year living in the UK.

Comment: I know it but I want it looks like this. Is it possible ?

Comment: @user48260 You mean you want to commit fraud?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a residential address in another country without commiting fraud.  If you don't live there it isn't your residence.

It is relatively easy to own or rent real property in (some) other countries.  It would not be difficult to receive utility bills or any other mail there, assuming there were someone to retrieve and pay them.  This is not the same as establishing residence.  Major cities worldwide are filled with propery owned by foreigners who do not live there and in fact may never even visit.